# Script that looks at 2 different datasets and sees if the unique combinations of values from the first dataset are contained within the second

Tags: python

I need to write a python script that looks at 2 different datasets and sees if the unique combinations of values from the first data set are contained within the second data set. These datasets are from excel but can be converted to .txt files.

Both datasets have 4 unique attributes "Name" "Age" "Weight" and "Height"

I need to check to see if each unique combination/observation exists in another dataset, and if it does not to print out the observation from the first dataset. I have provided a screen shot of what the data would look like. I have no idea of how many observations. Here are a sample of what the data will look like
[Dataset1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o21oi.png) [Dataset2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2UWQ.png)
as you can see in the Dataset1 observation 4 and 6 do not exist in the second dataset. I am new to Python, I have experience in R/SAS. So any help or advice is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine a representation for your datasets. Here, a simple example just uses a list of tuples (each tuple being a single record or row). Then, you can just use the `-` operator (minus) between two sets to get the result. Note that the records must be a hashable type for this approach to work (so tuple works)

Example with simplified data.

```py
# here you should read in files using the "with... open... as" clause
# combined with the readlines method of a file pointer
x_str = """a,b,1
c,d,2
e,f,4
g,i,3"""

y_str = """a,b,1
g,i,3"""

x = str_to_records(x_str)
y = str_to_records(y_str)

def str_to_records(data_str, delim = ","):
    """return list of tuples, each tuple being a row in the dataset"""
    if type(data_str) == str:
        data_lines = data_str.split("\n")
    return [tuple(line.strip().split(delim)) for line in data_lines]

def x_subset_minus_y(x, y):
    """return records in dataset x not in dataset y"""
    return set(x) - set(y)
    
x_subset_minus_y(x, y)
```

Output

```
{('c', 'd', '2'), ('e', 'f', '4')}
```